# Remove rows from table with unique IDs

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a bit of trouble figuring out how I could remove rows with unique IDs from my results.

Basically I am running this query:

```
SELECT 
    date(created) AS created, COUNT(customer_id) AS cnt, customer_id
FROM
    case
WHERE
    customer_id IN (16533 , 7186, 17727, 2442, 2646)
GROUP BY  DATE(`created`)
```

This will give me a list of of how often a customer created a case per day:

```
Date        cnt customer_id
2017-06-26  9   17727
2017-06-27  1   17727
2017-05-10  16  16533
2016-06-13  1   7186
2016-10-20  1   7186
2016-10-21  1   7186
2016-10-28  1   7186
...
```

The customer_id 16533 only appears once in the list and I would like to have it removed from the results??

Kind regards

Answer (score 2):

A little like this:

```
SELECT 
    date(created) AS created, COUNT(customer_id) AS cnt, customer_id
FROM
    case
WHERE
    customer_id IN (16533 , 7186, 17727, 2442, 2646)
    AND customer_id not in(
        Select customer_id from case 
        group by customer_id 
        having count(*)=1)
GROUP BY  DATE(`created`)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have news for you.  This query doesn't make sense:

```
SELECT date(created) AS created, COUNT(customer_id) AS cnt, customer_id
FROM `case`
WHERE customer_id IN (16533 , 7186, 17727, 2442, 2646)
GROUP BY DATE(`created`);
```

What value is `customer_id` *supposed* to have?  It returns just an arbitrary `customer_id` from that date.  It is indeterminate and could be any on that date.

If you want a list, then use `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT date(created) AS created, COUNT(customer_id) AS cnt,
       group_concat(customer_id) as customer_ids
FROM `case`
WHERE customer_id IN (16533 , 7186, 17727, 2442, 2646)
GROUP BY DATE(`created`);
```

If you want to eliminate customers that only appear once, do so explicitly:

```
SELECT date(created) AS created, COUNT(customer_id) AS cnt,
       group_concat(customer_id) as customer_ids
FROM `case` c
WHERE c.customer_id IN (16533, 7186, 17727, 2442, 2646) and
      not exists (select 1 
                  from `case` c2
                  where c2.customer_id = c.customer_id and
                        c2.case_id <> c.case_id  -- or whatever the primary key is
                 )
GROUP BY DATE(`created`);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * From (SELECT 
    date(created) AS created, COUNT(customer_id) AS cnt, customer_id
FROM
    case
WHERE
    customer_id IN (16533 , 7186, 17727, 2442, 2646)
GROUP BY  DATE(`created`)) t

Where t.customer_id NOT IN (16533)
```

Comment: I tested this is perfect missing way without pulling data to any other data set. if its ok. mark solve as solved

Comment: Thanks for your help Qaiser, but unfortunately, I think the missing the point. In the result example you don't see the result of ids 2442 and 2646, and therefore you cannot be sure if theese IDs appear once or more times. But thank you for your help

Answer (score -1):

If you are asking for customers who appear more than once, isn't HAVING the key here.....as well as grouping by the correct fields.....

```
SELECT 
    date(created) AS created, customer_Id, COUNT(*) AS cnt 
FROM
    case
WHERE
    customer_id IN (16533 , 7186, 17727, 2442, 2646)
GROUP BY  DATE(`created`), customer_id
HAVING COUNT(*) >1
```

If you're just looking to exclude 16533, don't have it in the IN set.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The HAVING clause would remove id's who's count is 1, in this case, tall lines having cnt=1 would be removed, i.e. `2016-06-13  1   7186`